# How to transfer money between accounts in authorize.net using php sdk?

Tags: authorize.net

We are planning to use authorize.net payment gateway for one of our business.

1) Is there a possibility to split a User's payment to two different merchants ?

Eg , If a User is paying me  $100 ,  20% of the user's payment should be sent to one merchant and the remaining 80% of the payment should be sent to another merchant.

Is this possible via authorize.net ?

2) Also please suggest, if there is any way to transfer money between the merchant accounts of authorize.net ?

Awaiting for your response at the earliest !

Comment: No to both questions

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.Net currently supports a single merchant account per gateway account so your use case isn't possible today.

Answer (score -1):

You need **stripe connect** for that.